# using UDF's and simpe dataframes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and come trying to do something like below
call a function PrintDetails for each cookie and then write the result into a file. The spark.sql query returns the correct data and I can serialize it to a file as well.
Can someone help with the for statement on each cookie. What should the syntax be for calling the UDF and how can I write the output to a text file?

any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def PrintDetails(cookie, timestamps,current_day, current_hourly_threshold,current_daily_threshold):
     #DO SOME WORK
     return "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%s" %(some_data)

def main(argv):
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("parquet_test") \
        .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "100") \
        .getOrCreate()

    inputPath = r'D:\Hadoop\Spark\parquet_input_files'
    inputFiles = os.path.join(inputPath, '*.parquet')

    impressionDate =  datetime.strptime("2019_12_31", '%Y_%m_%d')
    current_hourly_threshold = 40
    current_daily_threshold = 200

    parquetFile = spark.read.parquet(inputFiles)
    parquetFile.createOrReplaceTempView("parquetFile")
    cookie_and_time = spark.sql("SELECT cookie, collect_list(date_format(from_unixtime(ts), 'YYYY-mm-dd-H:M:S'))  as imp_times FROM parquetFile group by 1  ")

    for cookie in cookie_and_time :
        PrintDetails(cookie('cookie'), cookie('imp_times'), impressionDate, current_hourly_threshold, current_daily_threshold))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below.

```
cookie_df= cookie_and_time.withColumn("cookies",PrintDetails(cookie('cookie'), cookie('imp_times'), lit(impressionDate), lit(current_hourly_threshold), lit(current_daily_threshold)))
```

Or you can define all your variables in `udf` function itself and avoid passing as arguments.

Comment: Thanks Manoj! I changed the code to                                                                                                                                                                              
cookie_df = cookie_and_time.withColumn("cookies", PrintDetails(cookie_and_time('cookie'), cookie_and_time('imp_times'), lit(impressionDate), lit(current_hourly_threshold), lit(current_daily_threshold)))                      but I get the following error
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: Please modify your exiting dataframe schema as per your requirements.